# html5 range tag issue with firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, css, firebug

i am working with html5 range tag , i dont know why but i got issues with firefox. on chrome its working fine ...
 here is my code

```
<div id="slider">
5% <input id="slide" type="range"
 min="5" max="200" step="5" value="100"
 onchange="updateSlider(this.value)" />
 200%
</div><br/>
<div id="chosen">0</div>
```

and the css is

```
#chosen {
border-radius:10px;
width:45px;
padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc, #330000);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc, #330000);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc, #330000);
text-align:center;
color:#ffffff;
font-weight:bold; font-size:large;
margin-left:40px;}
#slider {
margin-left:10px;
}
input[type='range'] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #333333, #000000);
}
```

and i also use a little javascript :

```
function updateSlider(slideAmount) {
//get the element
var display = document.getElementById("chosen");
//show the amount
display.innerHTML=slideAmount;
}
```

Comment: [Firefox hasn't implemented `<input type="range">` yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: ohhh am unaware of that ... thanks for the info ...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox still hasn't implemented it. I'm not sure why, but they seem to have put HTML forms on hold somewhat.